# Spring Webflux: how to manually write headers and body?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm using Spring WebFlux for my project that is intended to work as pub/sub service: http clients connect to it and wait for events (like PUSH or SSE).

I need to manually write headers and body to the response without using `ServerResponse`.

I need to do it **manually** because I'm implementing an SSE server and I must send custom headers into the response before any event actually arrives.

I'm trying to do it this way:

```java
    @Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getStuff() {
        return route(GET("/stuff"),
                request -> {
                    final ServerWebExchange exchange = request.exchange();
                    final byte[] bytes = "data".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    final DataBuffer buffer =exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(bytes);
                    return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Flux.just(buffer));
                }
        );
```

But it does not work because `writeWith()` returns `Mono<Void>` and `getStuff()` must return `RouterFunction`. Can anybody help me find a way around this?

Comment: you have several problems, if you are writing an SSE server you should not be returning a ServerResponse since a Response ends the connection. You should instead return a Flux, preferrably with a ServerSentEvent object

Comment: I can not return a flux from RouterFunction

Comment: Actually, if I return RouterFunction<ServerResponse> and wrap it around Flux<ServerSentEvent>, it would keep the connection open, I even can add headers, but it would only send headers after the first event from the flux and I need it to send the headers right away.

Comment: Your sentance makes no sense. It will send headers for the first message but you want it sent right away. What?

Comment: Client connected -> gets headers -> waits for data -> data arrives. The point is that due to CORS restrictions, I need to send Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the browser, otherwise it will refuse working with my service.

Comment: why dont you just enable cors in spring security

Comment: Because it acts the same way as I described above. The headers are sent only when the first event arrives, but I need to send them immediately when the client connects. Spring Security & WebFluxConfigurer with CORS are not made for working with SSEs. I think I need to find a way to write all data manually, including headers and body, but I can't find a way to do this.